# How to distinguish whether a word is half-width or full-width?

Tags: python

Recently I've been dealing with texts with mixed languages, including Chinese, English, and even some emoticons.

I've been searching for this issue quite a lot, but the only thing I can find is "to replace full-width characters with half-width characters" rather than telling you how to determine whether the character is a half- or full-width word.

So, my question is:

**Is it possible to tell whether a word is half-width or full-width?**

Comment: Usually, if you want to examine text, you will put it into a compatibility decomposition form, such as NFKD.  If you do this, fullwidth latin characters become normal (halfwidth), and halfwidth kana/hangul become normal (fullwidth), making it easier to analyze the text.  You can do this in python with `import unicodedata; unicodedata.normalize('NKFD', text)`.

Comment: It's NFKD, not NKFD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In unicode 6.1, there is the block `Halfwidth and Fullwidth forms`, [pdf here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf).

Within this block, `\uFF01-\uFF60` and `\uFFE0-\uFFE6` are fullwidth, while `\uFF61-\uFFDC` and `\uFFE8-\uFFEE` are halfwidth.

Comment: \u00F01-\uFF60  is wrong, it should be \uFF01-\uFF60

Comment: @Lelouchcr Fixed! Thanks for the correction 3 years after the answer!

Comment: This isn't really a complete answer. Characters outside of the Halfwidth and Fullwidth forms can be either halfwidth or fullwidth, so using only that blocks chart as a reference leaves the vast majority of Unicode undefined.

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves There is no standard for width of characters defined; this existing width designation (half/full) only makes sense in certain contexts. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145712/320220) about `wcwidth`, which specifies full-width as 2 columns and every other normal character as 1 column wide.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a hard question to answer unless you have clear criteria of what is a half-width character and what is a full-width character. If you can decide on that, then you test the characters in the word against certain ranges in Unicode (or any encoding scheme).

The Unicode block [Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf) only shows you which characters have alternate forms. For any that do not feature in this block, you have to decide what you consider half- and full-width.

I would imagine that most Western characters are half-width, and most Eastern characters are full-width, but there will be exceptions in both. As [this Unicode report](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/) highlights, there are also ambiguities.

[This proposal](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/scw-proposal.html) includes [code](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/wcwidth.c) that seems to divide characters into full- half- and ambiguous-width. You could use those code points as a starting place.

Answer (score 0):

A word is full-width if its characters are full-width. You need to look up the unicode specification and see which character ranges are full-width, then check each character against that.