# C++ check if unicode character is full width

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, unicode, mfc

How to check if a unicode character is full width?

I use Win32 / MFC

For example, `中` is full width, `A` is not full width, `Ｆ` is full width, `F` is not full width.

Comment: +1 Your question made me go and learn something today!

Comment: @Pandrei I would _not_ recommend that article.  While it makes one or two useful points, there are also a couple of errors in it: for starters, the author doesn't seem to understand the difference _UCS_ and _UTF_.

Comment: What do you mean by Full width?

Answer (score 8):

What you need is to retrieve the [East Asian Width](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/) of the character. You can do it by parsing the [EastAsianWidth.txt](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/EastAsianWidth.txt) file from the Unicode Character Database. I could not find a Win32 API that returns this info, but in Python, for example, you can use [`unicodedata.east_asian_width(unichr)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html).

See the [Annex #11](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/) for the background of the problem and more information.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  FWIW: the various files from the Unicode consortium have been designed for easy parsing, so it shouldn't be too difficult to machine generate a C++ table from it.  (I've done this for a number of other such files.)

Comment: Are there any other languages other than East Asian have full width characters?

Comment: For a more complete discussion, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145712/53974

Answer (score -4):

What do you mean by "full width"?  The width of a character
depends on the font it is being displayed in.

If you mean whether it is a single byte character or not, it's
still not clear.  A single byte character in what encoding?  In
UTF-8, it will be a single byte character if (and only if) the
code point is less than 128; if you're using UTF-16 (probable,
since you're under Windows), just compare the character with
128.  A single byte encoding in ISO 8859-1 (another wide spread
encoding): compare with 256.  For anything less than 256, the
UTF-16 unit will be numerically identical to the code point in
ISO 8859-1 (sometimes known as Latin-1).  For the single byte
encoding ASCII (almost never used today, *but* most of the
common encodings are identical with it for the first 128 code
points), anything less that 128 is good.

Comment: @Roddy That makes more sense.  I should have looked up his second full-width character in my Unicode encoding.  (Of course, it basically means that there isn't a simple answer.)